# Is there a trace mode for Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to know (don't find that within the official documentation... but  ...) if there is some sort of trace mode for jenkinsfiles scripts ?
More specifically, my current concern is to trace the sshCommand step, to understand why something that runs "manually" fails within a pipeline.

Comment: May be these will help you as a start? [Logging - Jenkins - Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging) [How do I create a logger in Jenkins for troubleshooting and diagnostic information? – CloudBees Support](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204880580-How-do-I-create-a-logger-in-Jenkins-for-troubleshooting-and-diagnostic-information-)

Comment: Sure, it can help. Thanks a lot.
But I was looking for something simple and user-friendly, such as an environment variable to set... it would have been an interesting feature to have.
Well, for now on, I will log.
Thanks